# Wrong elevation of DEM

Tags: qgis, dem

I received a DEM made without calibrate the elevation with ground control points, the result is a DEM with 5 m below the real surface. How can I fix this issue if the plane coordinate are perfect, the only error is the elevation in QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html) to add 5m to the DEM.